# Can a Cypress script be written a way that it simulate 2 users working on the same HTML canvas?

Tags: html5-canvas, cypress

Lets say we have two instances of Cypress running in parallel and basically simulate two users working on the same Canvas. So user A adds an objects to the canvas, User B validates that the object was added to the canvas.

Don't know how to start please help.

Comment: Read https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-browsers-open-at-the-same-time

Answer (score 0):

I actually achieved this by using node js concurrent module along with wait-on and some combinational logic of cypress-wait-until library.